# Extjs6: dashboard parts coming vertically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I am creating my dashboard like this But when I render it, both my parts come vertically instead of being horizontol.Also there is a splitter vertical height between these two parts.How can I make them appear horizontally.

[image]

```
xtype: 'dashboard',
    defaultContent: [
        {
            type: 'dashChart',
            title: 'Graph 1',
            columnIndex: 0,
            height: 300
        },
        {
            type: 'dashChart1',
            title: 'Graph 2 ',
            columnIndex: 1,
            height: 300
        }

    ],
    parts: {
        dashChart: {
            viewTemplate: {
                collapsible: false,
                resizable: false,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'webdashboardpiechart'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    dashChart2: {
            viewTemplate: {
                collapsible: false,
                resizable: false,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'webdashboardareachart'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },



    maxColumns: 2
```

}

Comment: i think this is because your items are more than 50% wide. The first item is 636 px wide and the second is also 636 px wide, but the space left on the right is only like 618px wide.

Comment: @Alexander shouldn't the width be genrically managed by the dashboard class..as I am not supplying any width

Comment: Got the same issue inside a complex application.  No solution yet.  I guess some components are causing this but I'm still unable to reproduce it in a simple jsfiddle, Can you ?  Also, do you observe the same issue if you replace your parts with a simple panel like ({xtype: 'panel', html: 'panel 1'}) ?